# In matplotlib.pyplot, how to create label in x and y coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have dataframe named df, and I have successfully plot the bar plot by issuing this command below:

df.plot(kind="bar")

The graph is displayed, however, I have no idea on how to set the x label, y label and its title? Any idea on this? Is there any full fledge documentation available for this?

Thanks for your kind advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using pandas.  The dataframe plot method returns a matplotlib axes object.  You can call axes methods to customize -- http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xlabel('fred')
ax.set_ylabel('barney')
ax.set_title('wilma')
```